# How to build special permutation on SQLite3

Tags: sqlite

**I have this Select:**

SELECT modalityID, tagID, name FROM factors

**That gives me this result:**

```
modalityID   tagID   name

10           21      Ética
40           26      TESTE 
60           45      Contexto Social
```

**What can I do to build the permutations below:**

```
modalityID  tagID   name            ModalityID-B    TagID-B Name-B
10          21      Ética           40              26      TESTE 
40          26      TESTE           60              45      Contexto Social
10          21      Ética           60              45      Contexto Social
```

**Please, note that modalityID must be < modalityID-B and names without repetitions.**
All that I need is to generate all possible distinct permutations using the elements of just one table (factors). In other words the table "factors" must be compared to itself.

*Is it possible to create a select on SQLite3 to build this?*

Best regards

Comment: I'm sorry, but I can't understand your specification. Can you explain better what exactly you are trying to accomplish? Make a permutation of one or more fields? Is the permutation random?...

Comment: Do you mean you want each possible *pairing* (Carthesian product) of different rows in your original table?

Comment: Yes. Is that possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get this result using a self join with join condition being a.modalityID < b.modalityID.

[Here is a working example using your schema in sqlfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!5/4e62b/4)

```
SELECT 
  a.modalityID 'a.modalityID', a.tagID 'a.tagID', a.name 'a.name', 
  b.modalityID 'b.modalityID', b.tagID 'b.tagID', b.name 'b.name'
FROM factors a
JOIN factors b ON a.modalityID < b.modalityID
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this (didn't test):

```
SELECT A.modalityID, A.tagID, A.name, B.modalityID AS modalityID_B, B.tagID AS tagID_B, B.name AS name_B
FROM factors A, factors B
WHERE modalityID < modalityID_B
```